# Firefox Javascript IndexSizeError

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

So I've searched around this site for solutions to this problem and even though I've seen a number of posts that looked similar and I tried the different solutions offered, none of them seemed to work.

I'm new to Javascript and HTML and I'm trying to modify this game. It's a dungeon crawler where the player has to collect the items and avoid the monsters to win. I'm trying to modify it so that it also incorporates a health bar that drains when the player character collides with a monster and displays a game over when the health bar completely drains.

I'm having two issues. The game has two levels and my first issue is that the health bar only appears on the second level.

The second issue, like the post title says, when the player character's health bar drains to zero, the game freezes and the browser console window displays the IndexSizeError and it points to line 908

`if(sprite.visible && sprite.scrollable)
       {
         drawingSurface.drawImage
....`

Here's a JSFiddle link of the code, the HTML and other portions of the code like the collision detection and spriteObject code are in separate files.

The JS code in the link is the bulk of the functioning code and where the error seems to lie.

The strangest thing is, like other posts I've seen, this only seems to happen in FireFox because I tested the code in Chrome and everything ran fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/x82yo3ef/

Comment: Your jsfiddle code goes into infinite loop. It printed 'Loading..' 1000+ times (then I closed the window). You will need to put up some code that will reproduce the issue. Then only people will be able to help.

Comment: Post a [mcve] and make  sure that all your relative paths (ex. `../src/monsterMayhem.js`) are absolute paths that are true (ex. `http://sub.domain.com/src/monsterMayhem.js`. If an asset isn't necessary then omit it.